# Approximation $cos(x)= e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I found somewhere the approximation that for small $|x|< \varepsilon$ we have $cos(x) = e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$ and now I am looking for a more or less rigorous justification for it.

Comment: Do you know the respective power (Taylor/Maclaurin) series expansions of cos and exp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\cos x = 1 -\frac12x^2+\frac{1}{24}x^4+\cdots$

$e^{-\frac12x^2} = 1 -\frac12x^2+\frac{1}{8}x^4+\cdots$

So if $\varepsilon$ is small and $|x| < \varepsilon$, they differ by at most $\approx \frac{1}{12}\varepsilon^4$.

Answer (score 0):

They have the same value, slope and curvature at $x=0$ (verify this by writing the first few terms of the Taylor expansion - in fact the third derivatives are zero, too)